# I created a project with create-react-app. on my windows pc but when is try to run npm start on the command line it shows this error.please help me

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, react-dom

Got an error on npm start

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the raber-react@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

```
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\lectriweb\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-17T09_32_32_695Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\lectriweb\Documents\raber-react> npm start

> raber-react@0.1.0 start C:\Users\lectriweb\Documents\raber-react
> react-scripts start

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'emojis-list'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\lectriweb\Documents\raber-react\node_modules\loader-utils\lib\interpolateName.js
- C:\Users\lectriweb\Documents\raber-react\node_modules\loader-utils\lib\index.js
- C:\Users\lectriweb\Documents\raber-react\node_modules\html-webpack-plugin\index.js
- C:\Users\lectriweb\Documents\raber-react\node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js
- C:\Users\lectriweb\Documents\raber-react\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\lectriweb\Documents\raber-react\node_modules\loader-utils\lib\interpolateName.js:4:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\lectriweb\\Documents\\raber-react\\node_modules\\loader-utils\\lib\\interpolateName.js',
    'C:\\Users\\lectriweb\\Documents\\raber-react\\node_modules\\loader-utils\\lib\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\lectriweb\\Documents\\raber-react\\node_modules\\html-webpack-plugin\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\lectriweb\\Documents\\raber-react\\node_modules\\react-scripts\\config\\webpack.config.js',
    'C:\\Users\\lectriweb\\Documents\\raber-react\\node_modules\\react-scripts\\scripts\\start.js'
  ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! raber-react@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the raber-react@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\lectriweb\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-17T09_50_07_067Z-debug.log
```

Comment: `Error: Cannot find module 'emojis-list'` Looks like you're missing a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Node can't find the module called 'emojis-list'.
Open your terminal, go inside your folder and try installing all the packages with:

```
npm install
```

If it doesn't work, try installing the emojis-list itself:

```
npm install emojis-list --save
```